# Mongodb sort results by number of fields

Tags: mongodb, robo3t

I'm using robomongo to query a mongodb collection with millions of objects.

I want to see which objects have the greatest number of fields, and thus wish for the results to be ordered by the number of fields within each object.

So for example, I want to see objects with the greatest number of fields appear at the beginning of the search results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn't possible to sort results by the number of fields unless you explicitly save this count as a field in the documents. MongoDB doesn't know the number of fields in a document until the document is retrieved.

If field count is actually a meaningful value for your use case, you would have to write a custom script to calculate this (and decide whether you only care about top-level fields, or actually want to recurse into embedded documents/arrays).